# When using COPY with more than one source file, the destination must be a directory and end with a /

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I decided to use the [multiple source form of COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) to save an intermediate command but when I run it the following error pops up:

```
Step 17/22 : COPY --chown=$APP_USER:$APP_USER Gemfile Gemfile.lock $APP_PATH
When using COPY with more than one source file, the destination must be a directory and end with a /
```

In the Dockerfile I have this:

```
ARG APP_PATH='/usr/share/app/'

ONBUILD COPY --chown=$APP_USER:$APP_USER Gemfile Gemfile.lock $APP_PATH
```

---

#### Edit

Just to be clear, this happens with `ONBUILD` present and without, it just so happened I pasted in the `ONBUILD` example

---

I've tried with and without the single quotes. The arg has a trailing slash and is a directory so why is the build not honouring it?

I'd like to make this Dockerfile into a template using `ONBUILD` so it'd be good if I can make sure the `APP_PATH` arg is populated with a default that will work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer, as of Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4, is don't do it this way because it won't work.

I ended up hard-coding the destination directory (and the chown args too):

```
ONBUILD COPY --chown=app:app Gemfile Gemfile.lock /usr/share/app/
```

Answer (score 58):

In my case adding the (forward) slash at the end (following docker error message) was enough, like this:

`COPY package*.json .` # (fails!)

`COPY package*.json ./` # (works:)

Comment: This should be the right answer. Thanks.

Comment: While specifying any folder name, the folder name must end with a `/` symbol. For example: `COPY p* ./app/` and not `COPY p* ./app`

Answer (score 1):

Since `COPY` is in `ONBUILD`, `ARG` needs to be also in `ONBUILD`

You can think that Docker sort of copies (injects) your ONBUILD command right after the next `FROM`, at that stage it does not know your ARG if your ARG is not added with `ONBUILD`.

Comment: @iain did you try removing the quote?

Comment: Yes, it began without quotes.

Comment: Try removing --chown, currently it can't take ARGs.

Comment: After much fiddling around it's clear it can't work. Thanks for all your help, it's much appreciated and I gained some new insights into Docker that improved my build.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, earlier I set buildKit to false, so `Settings → Docker Engine`

```
"features": {
    "buildkit": true
  }
```